# (Auto)make dependency across multiple makefiles

Tags: makefile, automake

I am wondering if this is possible at all. Here is the situation:

My project uses automake to build its targets. The top-directory contains the usual `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`. Amongst others, the `Makefile.am` contains a `SUBDIRS` variable listing the subdirectories, important for my question is the `doc` and `include` directory. The `include` directory's makefile looks like:

```
nobase_include_HEADERS = <lot-of-headers>
```

so it basically installs the headers. The makefile in `doc` is supposed to generate html documentation out of those files:

```
doxygen-stamp: Doxyfile
    $(DOXYGEN) $<
    echo "timestamp for Doxyfile" > $@

all-local: doxygen-stamp
```

Everything works fine so far, but if I change any of the headers in `include` the documentation is still up-to-date - because I did not list them as dependencies. What I would like to have is to have a `doxygen-stamp`-target that is rebuilt once the headers change **without** again listing all headers as dependencies. Is that possible and if it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, using a single Makefile would be hinted at — though you can split it up by using the automake `include` instruction (also see section 7.3 "An alternative approach to subdirectories" of the am manual). Therefore:

```
#can't use nobase_
include_HEADERS = include/foo.h include/bar.h

doc/doxygen-stamp: ${include_HEADERS}
```

Comment: I do not like that this break the strict separation, but after thinking about it merging the Makefiles seems to be the better solution though.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you make doxygen-stamp also depend on '$(top_srcdir)/include/*.h' (or .hpp or whatever) it will rebuild when doxygen-stamp is out of date relative to any .h file in the include directory.

```
doxygen-stamp: Doxyfile $(top_srcdir)/include/*.h
```

Comment: Hm. I already thought about something similar, but in Automake these wildcard rules do not work!

Comment: I don't think that's automake, I think that's your make. We use GNU make and wildcard rules work fine (I hate them, but they work).

Comment: If you're using gnumake you might try this: `HEADERS := (wildcard $(top_srcdir)/include/*.h)`

Comment: +1 for explanations. I clarified my question a bit. A solution should not use GNU make since its not guaranteed to exist on all systems automake supports. Is it maybe possible to read the content of `nobase_include_HEADERS` in doc/Makefile.am?